# Unexpected number of values when reading integers from a text file

Tags: c#

I am reading integers from text file into an `int` array, so I use the following code. But it does not seem to read in the expected number of integers:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("D:\\pixels.txt");
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\print.txt");
string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int[] integers = new int[integerStrings.Length];
for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
{
    integers[n] = int.Parse(integerStrings[n]);
    tw.Write(integers[n]+" ");
}
tw.Write(integers.Length+" "+integerStrings.Length+" ");
```

In the file (tw) I get all the integers printed, but the `integers.Length` and `integerStrings.Length` are not correct. They should be 262,144 but they are both 41,616.
I cannot think of any problems.

Comment: Why aren't you using a regex for this? Seems like this is exactly what they're for.

Comment: @Yatrix Seems like the file is just numbers separated by spaces. Regex would be overkill when a simple `Split` will do.

Comment: Where do you get the number `262,144` from?

Comment: Yes, the file is integers, delimited by spaces. integers.Length equals integerStrings.Length and that is 41 616. But in the file I have 262 144 integer values.

Comment: @AnaZlateva Can you upload the file somewhere for us to view?

Comment: Here it is : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bC0Pm7i9d3aUGkb8Bif59PFLVLfrS_jP8S_fNlkrvfQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `$ wc -w ../pixels.txt 
41616 ../pixels.txt` <- your file contains only 41616 numbers.

Comment: Thank you all and sorry, everything works now! I was using a smaller picture to extract the pixel values from it, so it didn't have 262 144 (512x512) integers, but 41 616(204x204).

Comment: Really sorry! At least someone could use that, because it works!

Comment: @AnaZlateva Don't you love it when your program does _exactly what you told it to do?_ :)

Comment: I spent a few hours looking for a problem somewhere there was no problem! But thanks for asking me to upload the file so that you could tell me that I had the wrong number of values! So, my question is actually answered!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int dummyInt;
var integers = File.ReadAllText("C:\\temp\\pixels.txt")
                   .Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' })
                   .Select(n => (int?)(Int32.TryParse(n, out dummyInt)
                              ? dummyInt
                              : (int?)null))
                   .Where(n => n.HasValue)
                   .Select(n => n.Value)
                   .ToArray();
```

The above code should give you an array of integers that is read from input file, split by `' '` and new line and select only these values which can be converted into `Int32`.

Comment: You should avoid posting a wall of dense code like this without explaining its constituent parts for the OP. I've reformatted it so it is legible.